# I am trying to use following babel code to create Glitch Effect in my react app, but i don't know how to Implement it

Tags: html, reactjs, babeljs

I want to use this https://codemyui.com/horror-movie-like-glitch-effect/ code on my image in react, but I have no clue how to implement it.
What to install, where to add this code and if it'll work at all.
I'm new to React so any Help is appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This kind of question isn't really a great fit for this site, but here's the gist of what's going on: `imgSrc` contains image data (in base64), and JavaScript is iterating through its pixel array to randomly transpose pixels, create blocks of colour, etc. Then the pixels are drawn to a canvas. (The algorithm has little to do with React.) Broadly, your steps would be to use a site like https://www.base64-image.de/ to turn your image into base64-encoded data, then replace the string in `imgSrc` with that value. Don't use too large an image or your computer may start to choke on the calculations.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer,I am one step ahead cause you but should i copy this js code into Component? or? That is my main Question.

Comment: I imagine you could start by making a Component out of this - it should probably accept the image data in the props, transform it according to the algorithm (store it in the state), and draw the transformed data to a canvas in render(). Then recalculate the data on some interval (perhaps you can set that up in componentWillMount() and use setState() to update the rendered data). Note that the example you're looking at has a dependency on p5.js, so you may have to eliminate it. If you run into issues and have specific code, you can post it in a question and you'll probably get more responses.